# Analyze paragraphs using Neuroph

Tags: text-mining, clustering, neural-network, java

Currently we are regularly analyzing sets of paragraphs every month. I would like to automate this and split each paragraphs into chunks of data.

To do this I would like to employ a neural network. However, I am not really very familiar with creating neural networks.

Any ideas or starting point on how to do this using Neuroph or maybe in other framework/approaches?

Edit for more info as suggested.

I have very little experience on neural networks though I have some introduction with it in college. However I am very much familar with java

The data is around 3 megabytes only and consists of rules and relationships for a single domain. This means that the data is complex but relatively limited though still free-form English language.

Comment: This is quite open-ended. I would state more about your data, scale, what skills you have, what you have tried and what problems you're facing.

Comment: Even after the editing of the question, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to cluster the paragraphs?